# Burning tokens after the 'before' time slot?

Tags: minting

For a minting policy that specifies a 'before' slot requirement, it is impossible to mint new tokens after the specified time slot. Is it also impossible to burn existing tokens after the specified time slot?

Answer (score 2):

Not right now, but IOG is working for a way to burn these, so for now, keep them around!